# Youtube - New Livestream does not start until i dismiss old one

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am streaming video from an IP camera to Youtube using the restreamer software (https://datarhei.github.io/restreamer/) running on a Raspberry Pi 4.

Actually everything works as well. But when the stream is interrupted (for whatever reason), a new livestream is created only when I click on the "Dismiss" button in Youtube Studio.

But since I want to start the new stream automatically, I'm looking for a way to execute the click on the button (or the associated command) via the Youtube API.
How can I execute this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question because I found the problem description and a solution in another forum: https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/stream-didnt-show-error-or-load-to-youtube.130897/

> Something has changed on youtube in the last few days, but the solution to manage a real streaming reconnection is this: from the youtube control room from the manage icon, you need to create a scheduled streaming. Start the encode on this stream and everything will work fine. If the connection drops, youtube will say streaming offline; when the connection is re-established, streaming restarts.